# index() function in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way in tensorflow to get the index of a value in the tensor?

e.g. I have a one-hot matrix, and I want to get the coordinates of the 1.

```
| 0 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 |  => (1,1)
| 0 0 0 |
```

preferably this would be done with a function, e.g. `tensor.index(binary_function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/math_ops/sequence_comparison_and_indexing#where).

For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 3, 0]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coordinates = tf.where(tf.greater(x, 0))
    print(coordinates.eval()) # [[1 1], [2 1]]
    print(tf.gather_nd(x, coordinates).eval()) # [1, 3]
```